# Retrieving data from multiple schemas in a single database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema, union-all

I'm having more than one `schemas` inside a single `database`.

Say,

- DBTEST (Database)

  1. SCH001 (schema1)
  2. SCH002 (schema2)

Similarly, I'm having a table called `Tbl` which is present in the both schemas given above.
Now i had retrieved datum from the tables `SCH001.tbl` and `SCH002.tbl` by using the `union all` key word like this below,

```
select * From SCH001.tbl union all select * From SCH002.tbl
```

The above query is working with out any issue, But my boss is asking me to use some other technique to achieve the same(with out union all / Union). So what i am trying to ask is,
Is there any remedy available for Union all to get the same result in my case ? If not then, kindly tell the reason that why Union all cannot be replaced in this case.?

Comment: I would ask the question the other way round. Why *not* use UNION ALL ?

Comment: If your boss is so clever, maybe he will just tell you what technique you should use? If he doesn't know, maybe he should be quiet. Your solution is OK. union all cannot be replaced… let me think… because it is how you get data from two tables?

Comment: Before `UNION` was available in `MySQL`, we had to join on a dummy table. However, this was a kludge and not recommended for over a decade.

Comment: @SzymonGuz `If your boss is so clever, maybe he will just tell you what technique you should use?` This is what i thought while he was assigning the task today, Any how According from the discussion, i could finalise that there is no effective replacement available for UNION All. And by the way i need an answer to accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your boss thinks its ugly to use this union all (all) the time, why not make a view of it?
just reference all the fields in both union parts, and present this as combined view
(i say this cause its generally bad to use * in views)

<s>i do not know if you could index such a view, however its properly worth checking out,
i believe you have to use one schema only when doing indexed views, but i'm unsure of this
(however if possible, this would be a better solution than "just" the union)</s>

(new to that area)

:EDIT: you cannot (in Microsoft sql) make the materialized views on a union, and/or thereby on different schemas, (they are also schema bound)

i would personally use the view anyway, its just a nice way to give a programmatic interface to your data, that you can replace one day!.
:EDIT:

but fact is... its still a union under the hood

Comment: Using * in a `create view` doesn't make a difference. The view definition will store the list of columns as they existed when the view was created. The `*` will **not** be stored.

Comment: And you are correct, i guess it is my personal preferences, not to use * unless testing/looking for data